# web notifications not working

Tags: html, html5-notifications

I'm tring to use the web notifications API like in this example:
http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/10/notification-api/?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email

When i'm in this website, everything is working great, in the console i'm writing "Notification.permission" and gets "granted".

But if i'm trying to do the same in my website, i'm getting error about the Notification object and when i'm trying to print "Notification.permission" i've noticed that the Notification object doesn't have this property and other properties like "requestPermition".

This happening in all the browsers and they all updated to the last version.

i've tried to open console in other websites, like cnn.com for example, and inspect the Notifications object, and also there are missing properties.

Any idea why?? and how its working the website above??
thanks.

this is my code:

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var button = document.getElementById( "notifications" );

```
function theNotification() {

    var n = new Notification("Hi!",  {
    });

}

// When the button is clicked
button.addEventListener('click', function () {

    // If they are not denied (i.e. default)
    if (Notification && Notification.permission !== "denied") {

        // Request permission
        Notification.requestPermission( function( status ){

            // Change based on user's decision
            if (Notification.permission !== status)
                Notification.permission = status;
        });
    }
});

$(button).click();

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {query : "user=343"});
socket.on('notification', function (data) {

    console.log( data );

    if (Notification && Notification.permission === "granted") {
        theNotification();

    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: no code needed.. open the console in the example website and type Notification.permission.. you will get value.
try to do that in cnn.com and you will get an error

Comment: i've inserted my code